# Replacing values of a row in a dataframe by creating a new row, but keeping the modified original row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe as below, with all the values corresponding to an 'other' type, belonging to specific IDs:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"), type = c("oth", "oth", "oth", "oth", "oth", "oth"), value = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"))

 ID type value
  1  oth     A
  1  oth     B
  1  oth     B
  2  oth     C
  2  oth     D
  3  oth     D
```

I would like to change the types of the rows with values ***A, B, C to be 1, 2, 3*** respectively (D stays as 'oth'). If it is changed, I would like to keep the 'oth' row but have the value as NA.

The above df would result into:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3"), type = c("1", "oth", "2", "oth", "2", "oth", "3", "oth", "oth", "oth"), value = c("A", NA, "B", NA, "B", NA, "C", NA, "D", "D"))

 ID type value
  1    1     A
  1  oth  <NA>
  1    2     B
  1  oth  <NA>
  1    2     B
  1  oth  <NA>
  2    3     C
  2  oth  <NA>
  2  oth     D
  3  oth     D
```

Note that any rows that match A,B,C will create a new row with correct type, but change the original one to value = NA. If possible, a dplyr solution would be preferred.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a vector of values to change and filter (`values`). Filter those values and replace `value` column to `NA`. Use `match` to change `'A'` to 1, `'B'` to 2 and `'C'` to 3. Bind the two dataframes together.

```
library(dplyr)

values <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

df %>%
  filter(value %in% values) %>%
  mutate(value = NA)  %>%
  bind_rows(df %>%
  mutate(type = match(value, values), 
         type = replace(type, is.na(type), 'oth'))) %>%
  arrange(ID, type)

#   ID type value
#1   1    1     A
#2   1    2     B
#3   1    2     B
#4   1  oth  <NA>
#5   1  oth  <NA>
#6   1  oth  <NA>
#7   2    3     C
#8   2  oth  <NA>
#9   2  oth     D
#10  3  oth     D
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this way

```
df
rbind(df,
      df%>%
        filter(value %in% c("A", "B", "C")) %>%
        mutate(type = case_when(value == "A" ~ 1,
                              value == "B" ~ 2,
                              value == "C" ~ 3), 
               value = NA)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)

   ID type value
1   1  oth     A
2   1  oth     B
3   1  oth     B
4   1    1  <NA>
5   1    2  <NA>
6   1    2  <NA>
7   2  oth     C
8   2  oth     D
9   2    3  <NA>
10  3  oth     D
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be my approach, I didn't use dplyr but the order seemed important

```
my_df <- data.frame(ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "3"), type = c("oth", "oth", "oth", "oth", "oth", "oth"), value = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D"))

my_var <- which(my_df$value %in% c("A", "B", "C"))
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_temp <- my_df[my_var,]
}
my_var <- which(my_temp$value == "A")
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_temp[my_var, "type"] <- 1
}
my_var <- which(my_temp$value == "B")
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_temp[my_var, "type"] <- 2
}
my_var <- which(my_temp$value == "C")
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_temp[my_var, "type"] <- 3
}

my_df <- rbind(my_temp, my_df)
my_df <- my_df[order(my_df$ID, my_df$value),]

my_var <- which(my_df$type == "oth" & my_df$value %in% c("A", "B", "C"))
if (length(my_var)) {
  my_df[my_var, "value"] <- NA
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is potentially another `dplyr` option.

First, create a vector `vec` with the specific categories to `match` and obtain numeric values for.

Then, you can create groups based on whether each row `value` is contained within the vector `vec`. This allow you to insert rows, combining rows with `rbind`.

Within each group, the first row will have the `type` converted to a number, and the remaining row(s) with either `NA` for value (if `value` is in `vec`) or keep the same value.

This seems to work with your example data. Let me know if this meets your needs.

```
library(dplyr)

vec <- c("A", "B", "C")

df %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(value %in% vec)) %>%
  do(rbind(
    mutate(head(., 1), type = match(value, vec)), 
    mutate(., value = ifelse(value %in% vec, NA, value)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
```

**Output**

```
   ID    type  value
   <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 1     1     A    
 2 1     oth   NA   
 3 1     2     B    
 4 1     oth   NA   
 5 1     2     B    
 6 1     oth   NA   
 7 2     3     C    
 8 2     oth   NA   
 9 2     oth   D    
10 3     oth   D
```